# Filling one form from another

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two forms in my project, one is with button and second one is with two textboxes.
When I am clicking the first form button, I want to fill textbox in another.

code:

```
secondForm secondForm = new secondForm();
secondForm.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
secondForm.fillForm("String");

if (formShown != true)
{
    secondForm.Show();
    formShown = true;
}
else
{
    Application.OpenForms[secondForm.Name].Focus();
}
```

and

```
public void fillForm(string text)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(priceText1.Text))
    {
        priceText1.Text = text;
    }
    else
    {
        priceText2.Text = text;
    }
}
```

looks simple, but when i am clicking button second time, its not detecting text in second form text box and entering data in textbox1 instead of textbox2, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you click the button a second time you're creating a second instance of the form, and then just not showing it (you're focusing the first instance instead).  You should refactor the program so that you don't do that.

```
private secondform secondform = null;

private void Foo()
{
    if(secondForm == null)
    {
        secondForm = new secondForm();
        secondForm.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
        secondForm.Show();
    }

    secondForm.fillForm("String");

    secondForm.Focus();
}
```

So a new instance is only created if we don't already have one, we fill the data every time, and then focus the form.

P.S. there's nothing wrong with focusing the form the first time, so I just left it after the end of the `if`.  If there was something that should only happen when it's not the first time we could add an `else` to the `if` and put the code there.

P.S.S. `secondForm` isn't following standard naming conventions for the name of a class.  Class names should start with an upper case letter, i.e. `SecondForm`.  Among other issues, this removes the ambiguity about whether `secondForm` is refering to the type, or the instance of the type.

P.S.S.S. It may not be needed functionality in your case, but we may need to properly handle the case where the child form is closed and then the button is clicked again.  The easiest way of handling this is to clear out the `secondForm` instance field when the form is closed (letting a new one be created when the button is next clicked, if that ever happens).  Closures make this really easy, we just add this line right before `secondForm.Show();`:

```
secondform.FormClosed += (s, arg) => secondform = null;
```